# How can I wrap sets of elements into a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with `.wrap()` and `.wrapAll()` jQuery, but I can't seem to figure out a solution to the manipulating the code below.

I am working with so not-so-great markup and I'm trying to figure out how I can turn the following HTML:

```html
    <p class="category">Category 1</p>
    <p class="item">Item</p>
    <p class="item">Item</p>
    <p class="item">Item</p>
    <p class="category">Category 2</p>
    <p class="item">Item</p>
    <p class="item">Item</p>
    <p class="item">Item</p>
    <p class="category">Category 3</p>
    <p class="item">Item</p>
    <p class="item">Item</p>
    <p class="item">Item</p>
```

Into this:

```html
<div class="category-1">
  <p class="category">Category 1</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
</div>
<div class="category-2">
  <p class="category">Category 2</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
</div>
<div class="category-3">
  <p class="category">Category 3</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
</div>
```

I need to wrap from one `.category` to the next. I don't need the div that wraps each section to necessarily be the category name, I just named it that way for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over the `.category` and then wrap elements by getting up to the next `.category` element.

```js
$('.category').each(function(i) {
  $(this)
    // get element up to the next `.category` 
    .nextUntil('.category')

    // in case there is any other element as the sibling
    // then only get the paragraph element using
    // .filter('p.item')

    // add the current element to the object
    .add(this)
    // wrap it using the div
    .wrapAll($('<div/>', {
      class: 'category' + (i + 1)
    }))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="category">Category 1</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="category">Category 2</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="category">Category 3</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
  <p class="item">Item</p>
</div>
```